# The Dreaded Evercookie and CakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

So I'm trying to implement the [evercookie](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http://samy.pl/evercookie/&ei=yqaLTczdNseO0QGQltD-DQ&usg=AFQjCNGRGwZUVJq0woHDQEXoJARYUtgIKg&sig2=YnBEWp_FV8jwTBm1NXT9MA) on a cakePHP website, but I'm getting some really, really odd results.  I've just copied and pasted the code files into my app/webroot directory, and I don't seem to be getting any 404 errors, but my cookies are *not* saving--they're being rewritten each and every time.  What's even weirder is that when I load the page it sends **at least 90 GET requests to Google.com** and stores 4-5 SQLite databases in Google Chrome;  the evercookie website only stores **one**.

My code in my generated HTML page is this:

```
var ec = new evercookie();

// set a cookie "id" to a random 10 character string
// usage: ec.set(key, value)
ec.set("id", "vm5m172dyg");


// retrieve a cookie called "id" (simply)
ec.get("id", function(value) { alert("Cookie value is " + value) });



// or use a more advanced callback function for getting our cookie
// the cookie value is the first param
// an object containing the different storage methods
// and returned cookie values is the second parameter

function getCookie(best_candidate, all_candidates)

    {

    alert("The retrieved cookie is: " + best_candidate + "\n" +
        "You can see what each storage mechanism returned " +
        "by looping through the all_candidates object.");

         for (var item in all_candidates){

        document.write("Storage mechanism " + item +
                  " returned: " + all_candidates[item] + "<br>");

     }

}

    ec.get("id", getCookie);



// we look for "candidates" based off the number of "cookies" that
// come back matching since it's possible for mismatching cookies.
// the best candidate is most likely the correct one
```

Part of this code writes to my document, and here's the output (which looks fine to me):

```
Storage mechanism userData returned: undefined
Storage mechanism cookieData returned: d9g6mfoo4y
Storage mechanism localData returned: d9g6mfoo4y
Storage mechanism globalData returned: undefined
Storage mechanism sessionData returned: d9g6mfoo4y
Storage mechanism windowData returned: d9g6mfoo4y
Storage mechanism historyData returned: undefined
Storage mechanism pngData returned: d9g6mfoo4y
Storage mechanism etagData returned: d9g6mfoo4y
Storage mechanism cacheData returned: d9g6mfoo4y
Storage mechanism dbData returned: d9g6mfoo4y
Storage mechanism lsoData returned: d9g6mfoo4y
Storage mechanism slData returned: d9g6mfoo4y
```

My problem then is how do I prevent th 90+ requests that are sent to Google?  I have no idea why it's doing this.  If I have, say, ten users on the site at once (which is not unbelievable), that's over 900(0).  And do any of you have any idea why the cookie resets itself every time I refresh the page?  **That's exactly what I'm trying to prevent.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, don't I feel stupid!  It turned out that the ec.set() call at the beginning of the code was setting the cookie at the beginning of each page load.  So, I tweaked some things, and, uh, it's working now.  And I'm no longer sending 90 requests to Google.

```
// retrieve a cookie called "id" (simply)
ec.get("id", function(value) { 
    if(value == undefined){
        // set a cookie "id" to a random 10 character string
        // usage: ec.set(key, value)
        ec.set("id", "<?php echo $hash ?>");
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```